# Get double value from table with qsql

Tags: c++, qt-creator, qsqlquery

I am currently working on a program to calculate the price of material. My environment is Qt Creator. I am using sql database. I want to extract the value of genreDensity from my database table:

[image]

Unfortunately, the following code does not work:

```
double Database::GetMaterialDensity(int genreTypeIndex, QString genrePN){

double materialDensity = 0;

QSqlQuery materialDensityQuery("SELECT materialgenres.GenreDensity FROM materialgenres WHERE GenreType =" + QString::number(genreTypeIndex) + "AND GenrePN ="+ "\""+genrePN+"\"");

while(materialDensityQuery.next())
{
    materialDensity = materialDensityQuery.value(0).toDouble();
}

return materialDensity;}
```

Of course, I also use other functions that pull values from the database and they work without problems. It seems to me that the problem is here:

```
QSqlQuery materialDensityQuery("SELECT materialgenres.GenreDensity FROM materialgenres WHERE GenreType =" + QString::number(genreTypeIndex) + "AND GenrePN ="+ "\""+genrePN+"\"");
```

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?
Have a good day

Comment: You should never use string concatenation to build sql statements, use prepared statements instead. What do you mean by "doesn't work" does it return an error? What is the error?

Comment: "doesn't work" means return 0 value instead of 7.85

Comment: My guess would be that `materialDensityQuery.next()` returns `false`, have you tried debugging?

Comment: I checked and you are right. materialDensityQuery.next() returns false. I also checked materialDensityQuery.isValid() and I got the same result.

Comment: I modified statement "SELECT materialgenres.GenreDensity FROM materialgenres WHERE GenreType =" + QString::number(genreTypeIndex)" and now materialDensityQuery.next() return true. I think the problem is "AND GenrePN ="+ "\""+genrePN+"\"".

Comment: I fixed it. I just added a space before "AND": "SELECT materialgenres.GenreDensity FROM materialgenres WHERE GenreType =" + QString::number(genreTypeIndex) + " " + "AND GenrePN ="+ "\""+genrePN+"\"". However  you said I should create some temp string which will contains statement and then use this string inside of query? I will try. Thanks for help!

Comment: no, you should use prepared statements https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsqlquery.html#approaches-to-binding-values